# How to place 8 figures inside a page with subfigure

Tags: latex, figure, subfigure

I am trying to fit 8 figures inside a single figure. I am using 8 subfigures environments inside a figure environment and the code is woking reasonably well.

The first six figures are properly displayed as a matrix of figures with 3 rows and two columns. The other two, however, are not displayed as a fourth row. Instead, they both appear at the right hand side of the sixth figure and they do not fit in the page (see picture below).

The code below is a simple adpatation from @A.Ellet answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317295/how-to-make-8-subfigures-fit-in-one-page

I simply put one subfigure environment above the other. It works perfectly fine for 4 or 6 subfigures. But it does not seem to work for 8 subfigures.

I have already tried adding different spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill, \bigbreak but none of those worked.

[EXAMPLE OF HOW THE SUBFIGURES ARE DISPLAYED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfMoQ.png)

Am I missing any steps when using subfigures?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
 \begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Distribuições empíricas do \textit{bootstrap}}
  \label{fig:distrib_boot} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctpersist13.png} 
   \caption{$\Psi_{1,3}$} 
   \label{fig:distrib_boot_persist13} 
   \vspace{1ex}
  \end{subfigure}%% 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctpersist15.png} 
   \caption{$\Psi_{1,5}$} 
   \label{fig:distrib_boot_persist15} 
   \vspace{1ex}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctpersist23.png} 
   \caption{$\Psi_{2,3}$} 
   \label{fig:distrib_boot_persist23}
   \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}%%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctpersist25.png}  
   \caption{$\Psi_{1,5}$} 
   \label{fig:distrib_boot_persist25}
   \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctrazao.png} 
  \caption{$Im$} 
  \label{fig:fig:distrib_boot_razao} 
  \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}%% 
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctdin1.png} 
  \caption{$\Phi^{*}_{1}$} 
  \label{fig:distrib_boot_din1} 
  \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}%% 
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctdin3.png} 
  \caption{$\Phi^{*}_{3}$} 
  \label{fig:distrib_boot_din3} 
  \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}%% 
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctdin5.png} 
  \caption{$\Phi^{*}_{5}$} 
  \label{fig:distrib_boot_din5} 
  \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}%% 
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{graficos/pctdin3.png} 
  \caption{$\Phi^{*}_{3}$} 
  \label{fig:distrib_boot_din4} 
  \vspace{1ex}
 \end{subfigure}%% 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Try this, its 6, but easy to add two more :) https://github.com/mtkilic/Python-useful-scripts/blob/master/latex_file.py

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, it suffices to use \bigskip to change to the next row and \hfill between figures in the same row to keep an horizontal spacing between them.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!